# How to get time from SimpleDateFormate() in android?

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a String this:-

```
   Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 GMT+05:30 2012;
```

I want to divide  time & date from SimpleDateFormate:-

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss);
Date d = f.parse(my string);
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println("Date: " + date.format(d));
System.out.println("Time: " + time.format(d));
```

I am getting this Error:-

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 GMT+05:30 2012"
```

Please Tell me whats the problem.
Thanks,
Deepanker

Comment: Looks like the format you give to your SimpleDateFormat is not correct. It does not match your String format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp string does not match your pattern:

```
Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 GMT+05:30 2012
```

is no way like (not to mention syntax error in the SimpleDataFormat initialization line):

```
EEE,MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

So you need to make the pattern matching input data. All fields supported by SimpleDateFormat [are described here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the date is correct??
because I tried to parse it
it gives error on `GMT+05:30`
just remove the `:30` and it will work, see here:

```
String time = "Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 GMT+05 2012";
long f=Date.parse(time);
System.out.println("Time:" + f);
```

Comment: I am getting above string. You are right .I think that now i should use string split.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your timezone offset does not match the RFC 822 standard, so I don't think you can directly parse the date without performing some cleansing on it first.

If you just want an offset, then the string should look like:

```
Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 +0530 2012
```

Note, there is no "GMT", and no colon within the offset.  The corresponding pattern is then:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
```

Alternatively, you can specify the timezone:

```
Tue Oct 30 13:22:58 IST 2012
```

For which the pattern is:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
```