# SimpleDateFormat Error in android

Tags: java, android, date

I'm using `toLocaleString()` method to get this output "16 déc. 2012 23:00:28"
and then when I want to get the date back, I get `Unparseable date error`.

```
String s = "16 déc. 2012 23:00:28";
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM. yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date d = format.parse(s);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141511/how-to-get-time-from-simpledateformate-in-android

Answer (score 5):

Two things at play here:

- You should supply the locale (I believe French in your case?)
- The dot is part of the month short representation, so you are missing an 'M'

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.FRENCH);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your case

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(s);
```

your default locale is French, just remove '.'